# Customize returned Foreign Key object in toJSON sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have `user` object that has foreign key from `parentUser`. It's returned as the following.

```
user:{
    id:1,
    profilePicture: "",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    parentUser:{
        name: "John Doe",
        email: "john@example.com",
    }
}
```

What I need is to return object as the following:

```
user:{
    id:1,
    profilePicture: "",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "john@example.com",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make aliases for fields of `parentUser` using the `attributes` option like this:

```
const user = await db.User.findOne({
where: {
  id: userId
},
attributes: ['id', 'profilePicture', 'dateOfBirth', [sequelize.col('parentUser.name'), 'name'], sequelize.col('parentUser.email'), 'email']]
}),
include: [{
  model: ParentUser,
  as: 'parentUser',
  attributes: []
}]
```

Comment: It gives me `SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'user.parentUser.name'in 'field list` error

Comment: Probably you should indicate it as '"parentUser".name'

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `sequelize.col('"parentUser".name'), 'name'], sequelize.col('"parentUser".email'), 'email']]
})`